# Laptop Power Off Completely When No Input to It

Tags: windows-10, laptop

I have had my laptop (ACER ASPIRE) shut off after about 15-20 minutes when there is no input to it - no typing, no mouse movement.  It is a hard shut off, a power off.  Then I have to press the button to turn it back on.  It doesnt shut down, the power just cuts out completely.

I noticed this occurred after I replace the battery but I am not sure if it is the battery.  It only seems to do this when the AC power is connected and the battery is in the laptop.

I installed some laptop battery manager software that seems sketchy and things changed after that.

All power settings in Windows 10 tell the computer NOT to shut down after ANY amount of time.

Has anyone else faced this ?  Any idea what it could be ?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any related task was configured in Task Scheduler which may trigger the power off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A laptop should not shut down connected to AC. I have two laptops with manufacturer’s supplied battery threshold software and they run plugged in (at 80% charge) overnight with no input and do not shut down.

For certain, uninstall “some battery manager” as only the manufacturer’s software should be used. The manufacturer supplied software is tied to the BIOS, and that is why you must use manufacturer's battery software.

Restart after uninstalling this software and try resetting the battery. Charge to Full. Unplug and run down until the computer shuts off. Plug in and charge to Full. Restart and then see if the battery runs normally.

Normal means: Charge to Full, unplug, use for several hours, charge back up, repeat.

If the manufacturer does not supply battery (threshold) management software (a number of manufacturers do not) then just do not use such software.

If the manufacturer has battery threshold software, you can use that and set the battery to 80% to allow being plugged into AC for a sustained period.

If the battery is not working properly as described above, it should be replaced.

Have the machine cleaned (dust) and serviced at the same time.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks - How do I know the battery is "running normally" - what does that mean, running normally ?  How would I know - it is not shutting off anymore ?

Comment: In my instructions for the battery, the last step was to charge to full and restart.  You should then be able to unplug and it should last for several hours. Most batteries today go 4 to 6 hours. But it should not die within 30 too 60 minutes. I amended my answer to include this.

Comment: I tried what you suggested - unplugging it and letting it discharge.  It still does the behaviour of just shutting it self off - for seemingly no reason at all.  The only thing I can think of is it is getting hot, so it shuts off, but it just cuts out.  This behavior only started recently and maybe there is blockage in the air vents or something, but I am not really sure.  I am guessing at the battery here, but I tried that too and it just shuts off - cuts off and shuts down for no reason.  I thought also malware of something but it seems it is not that either.  I am stumped.

Comment: Have the machine serviced (cleaned for dust) and failures and have the battery replaced at the same time. I added servicing to my answer.